# Can I set the culture of a silverlight application from a page class?

Tags: silverlight, formatting, culture

In my SL application, I have a page that connects to a web service to retrieve some culture information such as date formats. As this information is not known at the instantiation of the silverlight application, I cannot set this in the public App() constructor. The following lines don't seem to work in the async completed method of the service call within the page class:

```
var dateFormatString = e.Result.DateFormatString;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = dateFormatString;
```

Is there a way to set the culture of the silverlight application from a page class?

Answer (score 0):

Set it in the main thread (your asyncCompleted is probably running on a different thread).
Let me know if you do not know how to do this.
There is no need to clone the Culture. (line 2 in your code).
Just set it directly:

```
var dateFormatString = e.Result.DateFormatString;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = dateFormatString;
```

** EDIT added sample code to call from UI Thread.
You can always pass state to an async wcf call. In this case I am passing a Dispatcher.
Once the callback is called use the Dispatcher to change the UI Culture in the UI thread.
I wrote this off the top of my head, but should be sufficient to give you an idea of what you need to do.

```
    public void SetCulture()
    {
        YourWcfProxy.GetCultureInfoCompleted += GetCultureInfoCompleted;
        object state = Dispatcher; // variable just for clarity.
        YourWcfProxy.GetCultureInfoAsync(state);
    }

    private void GetCultureInfoCompleted(object sender, GetCultureInfoCompletedCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = e.UserState as Dispatcher;
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // set the ui culture here!
        }
        );
    }
```

** EDIT 2 (answer question)

If you have a UIElement handy, you can use it's Disptacher property.
Otherwise use the static:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the reference to the dispatcher object of the silverlight application?

Comment: I tried this, but could not update the culture of the silverlight application. Instead, I've just gone for a less than ideal work-around, whereby I am ensuring I convert all the dates to string using my retrieved date format, before the databinding.